# Recommender System using ALS from ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have made some research and from what I know there are two possible ways to create a **Recommender System** using `Apache Spark`, one way is using the `MLLib` that comes with a pretty nice [example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#examples), which I have tried and is very easy, on the other hand you can use [ALS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS) from `ML`. I feel pretty comfortable working with `RDD`s, nevertheless I'm trying to use `DataFrames` more regularly to gain more experience.

To practice, I started using some crazy data where `ratings` are normalized, and I have over 4000+ records with only 5 possible products (as below). So my first challenge was how to convert this `DataFrame` to the required structure; structure that I guessed after several hours reading the source code.

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(List(Row(0.0, 0.12, 0.1, 0.0, 0.16),
                                                        Row(0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.52, 0.67))),
                                    StructType(StructField("product1", DoubleType, true) ::
                                               StructField("product2", DoubleType, true) ::
                                               StructField("product3", DoubleType, true) ::
                                               StructField("product4", DoubleType, true) ::
                                               StructField("product5", DoubleType, true) :: Nil))

df.show

+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|product1|product2|product3|product4|product5|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     0.0|    0.12|     0.1|     0.0|    0.16|
|     0.1|     0.0|     0.3|    0.52|    0.67|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I made several and somehow complex transformations, and I want to see if there is a better way to obtain the required structure.

```
val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, index) => row.toSeq.zipWithIndex.map(x => Row(index.toInt, x._2.toInt, x._1)) 
}.flatMap{x => x}

val (train, testing) = rdd.partitionBy(_.get(2) != 0.0)
val rdds = List(train, testing)
```

Then I convert those `RDD`s into `DataFrame`s.

```
val dfs = rdds.map(sqlContext.createDataFrame(_, StructType(StructField("user", IntegerType, true) ::
                                                            StructField("product", IntegerType, true) ::
                                                            StructField("rating", DoubleType, true) :: Nil)))
```

And after all these steps, I can finally use the `ALS` algorithm, and when things are so verbose, it's probably because you are doing something wrong.

```
val rec = (new ALS().setUserCol("user")
                    .setItemCol("product")
                    .setRatingCol("rating")
                    .setPredictionCol("value")
                    .setSeed(17)
                    .setMaxIter(20))

val model = rec.fit(dfs(0))

model.transform(dfs(1)).collect
Array([0,0,0.0,0.022231804], [1,1,0.0,0.102589644], [0,3,0.0,0.11560536])
```

Comment: What is your question Alberto ?

Comment: @eliasah How can I modify my code to make it more efficient, faster and less verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

- `user` and `rating` are default parameters for `userCol` and `ratingCol`. If you rename `product` to `item` you can omit this one as well.
- you can replace Row with Rating and omit schema later:

  ```
  case (row, u) => 
     row.toSeq.zipWithIndex.map{ case (r: Double, i: Int) => Rating(u, i, r) }

  ...
  .toDF
  ```
- since `id` seems to be irrelevant you can use `zipWithUniqueId`
- if `uniqueId` is acceptable you can use `monotonically_increasing_id` with `DataFrame`
- it is possible to avoid passing data to RDD by wrapping it with array an exploding:

  ```
  val exprs = explode(array(df.columns.map(c => 
    struct(lit(c).alias("item"), col(c).alias("rating"))): _*
  ))

  df
    .withColumn("user", monotonically_increasing_id)
    .withColumn("tmp", exprs)
    .select($"user", $"tmp.item", $"tmp.rating")
  ```

  and replace names with ids.

Nevertheless I believe there is not much to gain by using `DataFrames` here. One way or another data will be passed back to `MLlib` model which requires `RDD[Rating]`.